# Dynamic Components and Event Emitter in Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm a beginner in Angular, I am trying to deal with dynamic components (part of entryComponents in module.ts).
In the definition component, I have to select a row, then press a button  to open a modal (in EmailModalComponent) which contains 2 text fields and a text area (email address, email subject and email content);
after filling them, I have to run a function in definition component from EmailModalcomponent (with a button in the modal ) to 
send an email  with a pdf attachment containing the infomation of the row selected previously from definition component.
I had created a service that opens the email modal from definition component, an event emitter to send information from the modal to
definition component.
Everything works fine but the problem is that the email modal is always shown in definition component because I listen
to the event from the template.
Any suggestions please?

EmailComponent.ts

```
export class EmailModalComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() emailEvent = new EventEmitter();


  sendWithEvent(){
    this.emailEvent.emit({mail:this.emailTosend});
    console.log ("Sending event ... ", this.emailTosend)
  }
```

Defnition Component.ts

//the function to send the email 
(works fine)

```
 sendEmail($event) {
        let selectedRows = this.gridOptions.api.getSelectedRows();
        let id = selectedRows[0][Object.keys(selectedRows[0])[0]];
        var url = "/shared/emailModal/sendEmail"
        var filename;          
        this.definitionHttpService.exportPdf(this.serverUrl, id).takeUntil(this.unsubscribe).subscribe(
            data => {  
                let formData = new FormData();
                // The PDF Attachment part
                let mediaType = 'application/pdf';
                let blob = new Blob([data], {type: mediaType});
                filename = this.serverUrl.substr(1) + ".pdf";
                let emailAttachment = new File([blob], filename, {type: mediaType, lastModified: Date.now()});
                formData.append('pdfFile', emailAttachment);
                // The email part
                let email = $event.mail;
                let emailToSend = new Blob([JSON.stringify(email)], {type: 'application/json'});
                formData.append('mail',emailToSend);
                this.definitionHttpService.sendEmailAttach(url, formData).takeUntil(this.unsubscribe).subscribe();
            });

    }
```

definition Component.html

```
<app-email-modal  (emailEvent)='sendEmail($event)'></app-email-modal>
```

// it shouldn't be like this because I need to press a button to open the email modal

in Definition Component

[image: img1]

in the emailModal Component

[image: img2]

Comment: is the modal component from you or did you use a third party component?

Comment: Yes it's a component that I had created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the suitable way to solve this problem; I used MatDialog, and MAT_DIALOG_DATA from @angular/material to read and send data between the defintion component and the email modal instead of the event emitter.
Below is a good example describing this solution.

https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-material-dialog/

Answer (score 0):

Main template:

```
<parent>
   <child (closingChild) ="hideChild()"></child>
</parent>
```

Child component:

```
@Output() closingChild : EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

closeEmailModal() 
{ 
   this.closingChild.emit(); 
}
```

Parent component:

```
hideChild() 
{
   //Hide the email modal 
}
```

Comment: I don't need to hide the email modal, I just need to make it appear only when I click the email button not all the time. using it's selector make it there all the time:


<app-email-modal  (emailEvent)='sendEmail($event)'></app-email-modal>

Comment: @Farouk.ch What you are looking for is an overlay manager. It is a simple tool that launches and closes modal windows when needed and is very easy to integrate into your existing project. https://github.com/ng2-ui/overlay

Comment: @oneinazilion thank you for your help, my main problem is how to read the event emitter coming from the email modal, simply, I could open and close the modal but when calling this in template :
<app-email-modal  (emailEvent)='sendEmail($event)'></app-email-modal>

the email will be always there and when I click the button it will be shown too.
My question title is so clear : dynamic components and event emitters.
So I'm trying to find a way to read event emitters differently, I tried to use the ng-dynamic-component:
 https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-dynamic-component
But not working